# Swift - Initialize class variables without constructor

Tags: swift

in C# it is possible to do something like:

```
myClass() { var1 = 5, var2 = 6 }
```

So I can initialize variables of that class without the need of having a constructor for these variables like:

```
myClass(var1: 5, var2: 6)
```

Is it possible to do something similar in Swift?

Comment: `struct` will auto generate constructor for you.

Comment: If *all* properties have an initial value (and you don't provide any initializer yourself) then the compiler creates a default parameterless initializer for you, see "Default Initializers" in the Swift book.

Comment: ... and this applies to both structs and classes. In addition, structs can have a default *memberwise* initializer. So what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: @Bryan Chen: Ok, thanks, but I need a class

Comment: @Martin R: I am sorry but I am not exactly sure what you are referring to. I want to set some (not all and varying) properties of the class to an individual value when I create it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, for structs. No for classes.